# Некорректное отображение закруглённой рамки(border-radius) в Qt.ActionsContextMenu

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, qss, qmenu

Собственно. На лейблах и контекстном меню у меня один и тот же `styleSheet`. Однако в контекстном меню закругление работает не совсем корректно.

Если это возможно, то желательно без `qt.customcontextmenu`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import sys, os
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QMovie, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class MyWin(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        label.resize(300, 300)
        label.setStyleSheet('''background-color: grey;
                            padding: 5;
                            border: 1px solid #f09ea3;
                            border-radius: 10px;
                            ''')
        label.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.ActionsContextMenu)
        action = QtWidgets.QAction('text', self)
        label.addAction(action)
        

        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.resize(label.width(), label.height())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWin()
    w.show()
```

Comment: Опубликуйте минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который демонстрирует проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант. Проверено на Windows.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QFont
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QMenu, QAction, QWidget


class MyWin(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self._createActions()                                                # +++ 

        self.label = QLabel("Hello, World", self, font=QFont("Calibri", 20))
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.resize(300, 300)
        self.label.setStyleSheet('''background-color: grey;
                            border: 2px solid #f00;
                            border-radius: 10px;
                            ''')

        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.resize(self.label.width(), self.label.height())
        
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv       
        self._menu = QMenu()        
        self._menu.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self._menu.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self._menu.setStyleSheet("""
            QMenu{
                  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
                  border-radius: 10px;
                  border: 2px solid red;
            }
            QMenu::item {
                    background-color: transparent;
                    padding:3px 20px;
                    margin:5px 10px;
                    border-radius: 5px;
            }
            QMenu::item:selected { background-color: gray; }
        """)

        newAct = self._menu.addAction(self.newAction)
        openAct = self._menu.addAction(self.openAction)
        self._menu.addSeparator()
        quitAct = self._menu.addAction(self.exitAction)  

        QApplication.instance().focusObjectChanged.connect(self.focusChanged)    
        self._connectActions() 

    def _createActions(self):
        self.newAction = QAction(self)
        self.newAction.setText("&New")
        self.newAction.setIcon(QIcon("img/new.png"))
        self.openAction = QAction(QIcon("img/open.png"), "&Open...", self)
        self.exitAction = QAction(QIcon("img/exit.png"), "&Quit", self) 

    def focusChanged(self, obj):
        if not obj or obj.window() == self.window():
            self._menu.hide()

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        self._menu.hide()
        action = self._menu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(event.pos()))
        
    def _connectActions(self):
        self.newAction.triggered.connect(self.newFile)
        self.openAction.triggered.connect(self.openFile)
        self.exitAction.triggered.connect(self.close)  
        
    def newFile(self):
        self.label.setText("<b>File > <i style='color: red'>New...</i></b> clicked")
        self._menu.hide()

    def openFile(self):
        self.label.setText("<b>File > <i style='color: red'>Open...</i></b> clicked")
        self._menu.hide()
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWin()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]